# Gradle fails to load org.apache.logging.log4j dependencies properly

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, log4j

I am having an issue where gradle is somehow failing to make the org.apache.logging.log4j dependencies to the application.

Below is my gradle.build file,

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

group 'com.hf'
version '1.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs += ["-proc:none"]
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.11.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.11.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-jcl', version: '2.11.0'

    providedCompile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.3.7.Final'
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

It's seemingly straightforward. I have -proc:none because there seemed to be an issue with some deprecation otherwise. Regardless of whether proc:none is present in the gradle file, the issue persist. The output of gradle.build is as follows...

```
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :war UP-TO-DATE
> Task :assemble UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test NO-SOURCE
> Task :check UP-TO-DATE
> Task :build UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 6s
3 actionable tasks: 3 up-to-date
```

The dependency files are also present in the cache directory,
C:\Users\MY_USER_NAME.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j

containing the following dirs:
log4j  log4j-api  log4j-bom  log4j-core  log4j-jcl  log4j-to-slf4j

all of which have the respective log4j jars nested inside them.

The problem is that eclipse does not recognize the log4j imports,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYO2O.png)

As a result I can't compile my simple class,

```
package com.hf.config;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;


/**
 * The Config class reduces the amount of magic strings in the application via the
 * getProperty method. It has a static string CONFIG_FILE indicating the path to the config file
 * which must be set manually
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class AppConfig
{
    static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(AppConfig.class.getName());
    private static final String CONFIG_FILE = "./app_config.txt";

    /**
     * Gets a property from the CONFIG_FILE corresponding to propertyName
     * @param propertyName
     * @return a string value corresponding to propertyName
     */
    public static String getProperty(String propertyName)
    {
        Properties prop = new Properties();

        try(InputStream inStream = AppConfig.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(CONFIG_FILE))
        {
            if(inStream == null)
            {
                log.error("config error: did not find file '" + CONFIG_FILE + "', failed to load property " + propertyName);
                return null;
            }

            prop.load(inStream);
            return prop.getProperty(propertyName);
        } catch(IOException e)
        {   e.printStackTrace();            
        }

        log.error("config error: received property request '" + propertyName + "' which does not have a corresponding value in " + CONFIG_FILE);
        return propertyName;
    }
}
```

> > > I am very new to gradle, it's something we use at work so I am trying to incorporate it as a dependency manager for my personal project to get more familiar with it. Sadly I've spent two days now trying to find a solution to this issue and am hoping someone more knowledgeable or experienced can help me resolve this. Thanks for your help in adance.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved my problem by removing the project from eclipse and then re-importing it. That seems to have refreshed whatever settings were wrong and everything is working fine.

What I originally did in my frustration was install the IntelliJ IDE. When I imported my project into IntelliJ everything was working okay >___<.

That gave me the idea to remove the project from eclipse and re-import it which also fixed the problem in that IDE as well. I can only guess that gradle or eclipse were not updating the state of the project on some level.

While I'm glad to be moving passed this, I'm also rather annoyed. Hopefully this will be of some help to those running into similar issues in the future.